# How to delete the active table row in a ListObject?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform for inputting new rows of data into a dynamic table that is synced to a Sharepoint list. I just need the VBA code for deleting the active row in the table only.

I know this code is for deleting a specific row in the table:

`Selection.ListObject.ListRows(8).Delete`

But I need to delete the active row and only the active row in the table...

Comment: How do you know which is the active row in the table? `ActiveCell.Row` can tell you which row of the worksheet is active.

Comment: I'm aware of how to get the active row, I need the code for deleting the active listrow of the table. Not through the selection of the entire row or a rang of cells, I need to delete the actual list row of the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the active table row using:

`Selection.Row - Selection.ListObject.Range.Row`

Putting it together with what you have:

```vb
Dim ActiveTableRow As Long
ActiveTableRow = Selection.Row - Selection.ListObject.Range.Row
Selection.ListObject.ListRows(ActiveTableRow).Delete
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoiding the usage of `Select` and `Activate` is probably the first step to become a better VBA developer - [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Thus, the easiest way to do it is this one:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

However, if you like to go one step further, then a more general function can be created:

```
Sub DeleteRow(rowNumber As Long, _
                Optional ws As Worksheet, _
                Optional wb As Workbook)

    If wb Is Nothing Then
        Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    End If

    If ws Is Nothing Then
        Set ws = ActiveSheet
    End If

    ws.Cells(rowNumber, 1).EntireRow.Delete

End Sub

Sub TestMe()

    DeleteRow ActiveCell.Row

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for deleting the active row.

```
x = ActiveCell.Row
Rows(x).Select
Selection.ActiveRow.Delete
```

This help?  Works in a table or grid.

Comment: I'm aware on how to delete an active row. What I am looking to do though is remove a list row from a table. Deleting an active row just clears contents in all the cells of the active row. I need to remove a row from a table and that row needs to be the active row.